# Http 400 Bad request error when updating resource in RESTful web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, post

I have a Spring 4 web application that supports user accounts. It has a web front-end for creating accounts and logging in. Now I am trying to create new users using REST web service. I am able to `get` and `delete` users using web service but when I try to create a new user or update an existing user I am getting http 400 error - Bad Request. Below is my code.

Service method for creating user:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createuser", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json", produces="application/html")
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody User user){
    logger.debug("insdie put");
    logger.debug(user);
    boolean result = userService.createUserServices(user);
    if(result){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

URL & Data:

```
http://localhost:8080/XXX/createuser

{
  username: "arun.talwar1@yahoo.com",
  enabled: 1
  password: "arun"
  authority: {
    username: "arun.talwar1@yahoo.com"
    authorityType: "candidate"
  },
  userDetails: {
    username: "arun.talwar1@yahoo.com"
    firstName: "Arun1"
    lastName: "Talwar"
  }
}
```

Request & Response:

```
POST /DummyJobPortal/services/createuser HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 233
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1011
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 17:26:12 GMT
Connection: close
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private int enabled;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
private Authority authority;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
private UserDetails userDetails;

@XmlElement(name="userDetails")
public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
    return userDetails;
}

public void setUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
    this.userDetails = userDetails;
}

@XmlElement(name="authority")
public Authority getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}

public void setAuthority(Authority authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

@XmlElement(name="username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@XmlElement(name="password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@XmlElement(name="enabled")
public int getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

}
```

I have gone through the internet looking for answers but it points to malformed request and server is unable to understand request. But this is the same format I am getting when I request a user using http `get` method. Any suggestions, most welcome.

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint inside of that method?  Do you see it getting called at all?

Comment: @Makoto No, it is not called.

Comment: What's the full path?  Is there a parent-level `@RequestMapping("/XXX")` on the class?

Comment: @Makoto yes, it is `@RequestMapping(value="/services")` and full path is `http://localhost:8080/xxx/services/createuser`

Comment: What does the error say when you make the bad request?  Do you get any kind of exception or stack trace?

Comment: @Makoto there is no server stack trace but in the description it says `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

Comment: Does the client include a "Content-Type" header with a value of "application/json"?  The "Accepts" annotation on the server method implies that might be necessary.

Comment: How are you attempting to POST/PUT? Postman, cURL, etc? Can you post the request you are attempting to send as well?

Comment: Are you sure the request method is `POST`?

Comment: @EJK I am using Google chrome rest client for testing and yes I have set the content-type to applicatoin/json

Comment: Could you please update your question so that the "URL & Data" section shows the complete HTTP trace of the request.  What you have there is incomplete and that prevents us from being able to answer your question.  Note that earlier comments are asking for this as well.

Comment: @EJK added the request and response headers

Comment: Note that your JSON is mal-fromed.  Your attributes need to be comma-separated.  A recent edit added these commas.  I just rolled-back that edit when it occurred to me that this might be your very problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is mal-fromed which will prevent the server from being able to process your request. Your attributes need to be comma-separated, and your attribute names need to be quoted.

Here is a correctly formatted version of your JSON

```
{
    "username": "arun.talwar1@yahoo.com",
    "enabled": 1,
    "password": "arun",
    "authority": {
        "username": "arun.talwar1@yahoo.com",
        "authorityType": "candidate"
    },
    "userDetails": {
        "username": "arun.talwar1@yahoo.com",
        "firstName": "Arun1",
        "lastName": "Talwar"
    }
}
```

Presumably the 400-BadRequest response was due to the fact that the server could not parse your JSON request.

Comment: No. that is not it. Still get the error. Is therer a way I can view the whole error trace of it.